# MediaEngine audio playback on WinRT

Tags: mp3, windows-runtime, ogg

I'm trying to add music to my game that runs on WinRT. The music should be in an encoded format (mp3, ogg, etc.) and should be streamable and be decoded by the hardware (for performance reasons).

I've looked through the samples, and found out that MediaEngine can do something like this (I hope).

However, I'm having problems making it work. I keep getting ComExceptions everytime I try to create `IMFByteStream` from `IRandomAccessStream` via `MFCreateMFByteStreamOnStreamEx()`.

It might be that I'm not handling tasks correctly, since they are a new paradigm for me.

Here's some code (pretty similar to the sample I mentioned before):

```
void MyMedia::PlayMusic ()
{
    try
    {
        StorageFolder^ installedLocation = Windows::ApplicationModel::Package::Current->InstalledLocation;

        Concurrency::task<StorageFile^> m_pickFileTask = Concurrency::task<StorageFile^>(installedLocation->GetFileAsync("music.mp3"), m_tcs.get_token());

        SetURL(StringHelper::toString("music.mp3"));

        auto player = this;
        m_pickFileTask.then([&player](StorageFile^ fileHandle)
        {
            Concurrency::task<IRandomAccessStream^> fOpenStreamTask = Concurrency::task<IRandomAccessStream^> (fileHandle->OpenAsync(Windows::Storage::FileAccessMode::Read));
            fOpenStreamTask.then([&player](IRandomAccessStream^ streamHandle)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        player->SetBytestream(streamHandle);

                        if (player->m_spMediaEngine)
                        {
                            MEDIA::ThrowIfFailed(
                                player->m_spMediaEngine->Play()
                                );

                        }
                    } catch(Platform::Exception^)
                    {
                        MEDIA::ThrowIfFailed(E_UNEXPECTED);
                    }

                }
            );  
        }
        );

    } catch(Platform::Exception^ ex)
    {
        Printf("error: %s", ex->Message);
    }


}

void MyMedia::SetBytestream(IRandomAccessStream^ streamHandle)
{
    HRESULT hr = S_OK;
    ComPtr<IMFByteStream> spMFByteStream = nullptr; 

    //The following line always throws a ComException
    MEDIA::ThrowIfFailed(
        MFCreateMFByteStreamOnStreamEx((IUnknown*)streamHandle, &spMFByteStream)
        );

    MEDIA::ThrowIfFailed(
        m_spEngineEx->SetSourceFromByteStream(spMFByteStream.Get(), m_bstrURL)
        );  

    return;
}
```

**Bonus**: If you know a better solution to my audio needs, please leave a comment.

Comment: Regarding hardware decoding: that depends on the hardware (see http://blogs.msdn.com/b/b8/archive/2012/06/08/building-a-rich-and-extensible-media-platform.aspx for a more complete overview)

Comment: Thanks for the link. I'm counting on that all the major hand-held devices would be able to do this. Or else they are not viable gaming platforms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to fix this. There was two problems I found.

- Media Foundation was not initialized

`MFStartup(MF_VERSION);` needs to be called before Media Foundation can be used. I added this code just before creating the media engine.

- Referencing a pointer.

Line `m_pickFileTask.then([&player](StorageFile^ fileHandle)` should be `m_pickFileTask.then([player](StorageFile^ fileHandle)`. `This` is already a pointer to the current class, and `&` provides the address of variable, so I was actually passing the pointer's pointer.